# non constant morphism of integral curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f: C_1 \to C_2$ be a non constant morphism of integral curves. by a curve I mean a  proper one dimensional scheme over fixed base field $k$. I saw often the usage of the fact that under assumptions above $f$ is a finite morphism; especially an affine one. is there a standard way to verify it? unfortunately I could nowhere find a complete proof of this statement.

as far as I'm concerned I would it do by proper + finite fibers imply finiteness but since this theorem imcluding it's proof seems to be a heavy gun for me therefore I'm looking with keen interest for a more "standard" proof of the statement above. additionally, does it also hold if the curves are irreducible instead of integral?

Comment: I think the "proper + finite fibres" is "finite" is the right way of showing this.  On the other hand, you could also appeal to the "proper +affine" is "finite" statement. But this would require you showing first that any open subset  $U\subsetneq X$ of an integral curve  $X$ is affine. This is considerably more work. The "proper +quasi-finite" line of reasoning is much more direct in this case.

Comment: You could also appeal to Zariski's Main Theorem (the one that says that quasi-finite separated morphisms factor over an open immersion and a finite morphism) in your situation to se that $f$ is finite. The point I'm trying to make is that proving that a morphism is finite will (almost always?)  require some type of "heavy gun".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an argument in the projective case that I learned from Vakil's notes. The heaviest tool it uses is Grothendieck's coherence theorem for projective morphisms.
If you don't want to assume that $C_1$ is projective, you need to prove that proper curves are projective or use Chow's lemma to prove an analogous result in the case where $\pi$ is only assumed to be proper.

**Theorem 18.1.8.** Let $Y$ be a locally noetherian scheme, and let $\pi \colon X \to Y$ be a projective morphism. Then $\pi$ has finite fibers if and only if it is finite.

**Proof.**
"If" is easy (finite schemes over a field have finitely many points), so we turn to "only if". It suffices to work locally around a point $y$ of $Y$.
We may assume that $Y$ is affine, $X$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_Y$, and $\pi$ is the restriction of the canonical projection $\mathbb{P}^n_Y \to Y$ to $X$. Let $S$ be the homogeneous coordinate ring of $\mathbb{P}^n_Y$.

Because $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is finite, graded prime avoidance tells us that there exists a nonzero homogeneous element $s$ of $S$ of positive degree such that the hypersurface $H = V_+(s)$ defined by $s$ does not meet $\pi^{-1}(y)$. Note that $X \smallsetminus H$ is affine, because it is closed in the affine scheme $\mathbb{P}^n_Y \smallsetminus H$; in particular the restriction $X \smallsetminus H \to Y$ of $\pi$ to $X \smallsetminus H$ is affine.

Since $\pi$ is closed, $\pi(H \cap X)$ is closed in $Y$. Let
$$V = Y \smallsetminus \pi(H \cap X),$$
which is an open neighborhood of $y$ in $Y$. Then $\pi^{-1}(V) \subset X \smallsetminus H$, so
$$
\pi|_{\pi^{-1}(V)} \colon \pi^{-1}(V) \to V
$$
is affine as a base change of the affine morphism $X \smallsetminus H \to Y$.

By Grothendieck's coherence theorem, $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent; thus $\pi|_{\pi^{-1}(V)}$ is even finite. **q.e.d.**

**Corollary.** Let $k$ be a field and let $\pi \colon C \to Y$ be a nonconstant $k$-morphism from an irreducible projective $1$-dimensional $k$-scheme to a locally noetherian separated $k$-scheme. Then $f$ is finite.

**Proof.** The assumptions imply that $\pi$ is projective; by the preceding result it suffices to show that its fibers are finite. Let $y$ be a point of $Y$. Then $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is a closed subset of $Y$, and it is not equal to $Y$ because $\pi$ is not constant. Thus it is finite. **q.e.d.**

Comment: why is $X \backslash H=D_{+}(s)$ affine for "arbitrary" homogeneous section? in general in is not contained in standard affine $D_+(T_i)$

Comment: This is true by definition: The scheme $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is obtained by identifying $D_+(s)$ with $\operatorname{Spec}(S_{(s)})$ (homogeneous localization) and gluing; see e.g. [EGA **II**, 2.4.1].

Comment: As for why this _should_ be true, you can use the $d$-uple embedding (for $d = $ degree of $s$) to reduce to the case of a hyperplane.

Comment: @user616417 This is very nice.